# How does webpack dynamically load modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How does webpack handle dynamic loading of modules? Since webpack is a bundler that executes at build time, and it often includes plugins that transpiles all imports, how is it possible to have the same type of import at run time?

The runtime, whether it is node or the browser, would have to call into webpack to transpile the import, which isn't really possible. How is that done?